# Rails, Devise, Heroku deleting user account from Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have some empty user accounts sitting in my production environment that I made as a test, that I'd like to delete now. They don't have any items that are attached to them, so what command do I run from the heroku console to delete these? Also, I access the heroku console by just typing 'heroku console', right?

I deleted the "User Delete" button from the devise view because I didn't want users to be able to delete their accounts... Figured this was the cleanest way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the easiest way is to open a heroku console and delete manually each user you want to delete. I would advise you to be *extremely* careful since it is a production environment.

```
heroku run console -a <YOUR APP NAME>
User.find(list_of_ids).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to Heroku console by typing this:

```
heroku run rails c
```

Just in case, you want to delete a certain user like me, you can use this command where id is the id of the user.

```
User.find_by!(id: 6).destroy!
```